# Adobe Air addEventListener Not registering

Tags: air, drag-and-drop, adobe, addeventlistener

Sorry, I'm new to using Adobe Air and I'm not sure why my

`addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_ENTER, onDragIn);`

and

`addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP, onDragDrop);`

lines aren't registering. It is giving me an error that says "Call to possibly undefined method addEventListener"

I'm attempting to load the application and using the following code example from: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2007/11/07/air-example-native-drag-and-drop/

This is my DragAndDropExampleClass.as: http://pastebin.com/SNZyW5Cx

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mike Chamber's example, the code in the file `DragAndDropExampleClass` is meant to be used as inline code, it's not an actual class.

As such, you removed the package/class directives. That should have cleared up the problems you were having (as described in the comment trail).

Including code inline with the script tag `<mx:Script source="DragAndDropExampleClass.as" />` is a bad practice, however, and perhaps leading to your confusion. I've taken your two files and combined them into one application below. It's literally the same as the Mike Chambers example, just in one file. Maybe this will help. I've run this application and it works.

Note: I compiled it with Flash Builder 4.6, so the code is a little different. If you're using Flex 3, try combining Mike's two pieces of code like I did.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;
            import flash.desktop.NativeDragManager;
            import flash.display.Sprite;
            import flash.events.NativeDragEvent;
            import flash.filesystem.File;
            import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
            import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

            //called when app has initialized and is about to display
            protected function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                //register for the drag enter event
                addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_ENTER, onDragIn);

                //register for the drag drop event
                addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP, onDragDrop);
            }

            //called when the user drags an item into the component area
            protected function onDragIn(e:NativeDragEvent):void
            {
                //check and see if files are being drug in
                if(e.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT))
                {
                    //get the array of files
                    var files:Array = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;

                    //make sure only one file is dragged in (i.e. this app doesn't
                    //support dragging in multiple files)
                    if(files.length == 1)
                    {
                        //accept the drag action
                        NativeDragManager.acceptDragDrop(this);
                    }
                }
            }

            //called when the user drops an item over the component
            protected function onDragDrop(e:NativeDragEvent):void
            {
                //get the array of files being drug into the app
                var arr:Array = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;

                //grab the files file
                var f:File = File(arr[0]);

                //create a FileStream to work with the file
                var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();

                //open the file for reading
                fs.open(f, FileMode.READ);

                //read the file as a string
                var data:String = fs.readUTFBytes(fs.bytesAvailable);

                //close the file
                fs.close();

                //display the contents of the file
                outputField.text = data;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <mx:TextArea top="10" right="10" bottom="10" left="251"
                 id="outputField" />
    <mx:Text text="Drag a Text File into the Application"
             width="233" height="148" top="11" left="10"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll have to look into what this all means now!

Comment: I just edited my answer. The first one was correct (your app would have compiled), but your app would not have run if the class was merely an EventDispatcher :)

Comment: Would you happen to know how to have my outputField identified within my class? There is a textArea with the id = "outputField" within the main application but it's not registering within my DragAndDropExample Class. The main app is here: http://pastebin.com/iYCYuTjh

Comment: Ok, my apologies, the first time I clicked the link to Mike Chamber's blog, it took so long I didn't see his example code. My answer is not quite correct. Since you are including inline actionscript (DragAndDropExample) in your MXML that code should **not** be in a class. It's going to be part of whatever class you include it in... (editing my answer)

Comment: I appreciate your continued help with this! I took out the package{} and class{} from my DragAndDropExampleClass.as and now I'm still confused as to what I'm trying to do. How do I now define the addEventListener? Or are you saying that I don't need this DragAndDropExampleClass.as file at all? Here's the DragAndDropExampleClass.as http://pastebin.com/Bn0pA4EG

Comment: Are you still getting errors? Basically, the code inside the file DragAndDropExample is being included inside the class for your main application. By removing the package/class stuff, made it possible for that code to be used inline. It should compile now, as the addEventListener method is defined in your main application.

Comment: I see. I've removed it but the addEventListener method isn't being registered. I don't think its actually being defined in the main application.

Comment: I've been biting my tongue about that example, until now. Edited my answer to combine the original code into one runnable application. Maybe that will help :)